# Recently updated to windows 10, just downloaded the lastest version of git but git-bash won't run on my windows 10

Tags: bash, git, windows-10

Recently, I updated my windows to version 10. Just installed the latest version of Git (2.27.0) but git-bash has refused to run after launching. Git-bash worked perfectly on my previous windows 7 but can't launch now. After clicking on the created Git-bash shortcut on desktop nothing happens. The other git tools Git-GUI and Git-CMD launches and works fine, only Git-bash doesn't. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling git but still git-bash fails to launch. I've also gone through related articles here but can't solve this issue. I'm new to git so any help will be very much appreciated. I'm using a 32 bit OS.

Comment: 32 vs 64 bit OS - software issue?

Comment: @Nic3500, I'm using a 32 bit OS.

Comment: Perhaps open a terminal and run the exe from there and see if it spits out a message.

Comment: Do you have anti virus software installed? Maybe that is interfering.

Comment: @lurker I did just that by opening the link to bash through the cmd prompt. It worked perfectly without throwing error message. Thanks man, issue solved, I appreciate.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt  I wasn't using any anti-virus software, but was able to resolve issue by assessing bash through the cmd prompt.Regards.

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with the shortcut path. You could fox it manually